# Mysql only update if where data is in latin8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have this statement which works in the first run

```
UPDATE accounts SET username = CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(username USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8)
```

This would convert latin1 characters into UTF8 chinese character in mysql.

Running it the **2nd time**, the character will become weird.

How do I add in a **where condition** that only update username to utf8 from latin1 if the word is currently in latin1

Comment: I don't understand your converting things. If you want to avoid 2nd convert, just add another column to set it to 1 for every rows you already converted. Next time, skip those rows.

Answer (score 0):

What is the `CHARACTER SET` for the column?  If it is still `latin1`, you are asking for a lot of trouble.

A table declared to be latin1, and containing latin1 bytes can be converted to utf8 via

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

After that (and assuming you have `SET NAMES` set correctly), text will be converted to utf8 as it is inserted.  No need to a flag; no need for second pass; etc.